# Convert timestamp to seconds in Excel

Tags: excel, type-conversion

How to convert timestamps in Excel to seconds. For example, I have 00:04:01.394 and after conversion it should be:

```
00:04:01.394 -> 241
```

Comment: Hint: there are 1440 minutes in a day and 60 seconds in a minute.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the following formula where A2 is the cell containing the timestamp:

=HOUR(A2) * 3600 + MINUTE(A2) * 60 + SECOND(A2)

Reference: [Convert Time in Excel](http://www.excelfunctions.net/Convert-Time-To-Decimal.html)

Answer (score 2):

use the below formula

```
=((HOUR("00:04:01.394")*3600)+(MINUTE("00:04:01.394")*60)+(SECOND("00:04:01.394")))
```